# In Windows XP I deleted my ubuntu partiton

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, grub

But the problem is much greater then that. The version of Ubuntu I have is netbook remix 9.10, I believe it to be grub 2.

I am getting the screen grub recovery, but there is no grub it was deleted. I have tried uses the super boot disk, but my computer won't boot to it. Even after making it first priority.

I need to know the command by command to boot windows thought just the grub recovery that is all I have to work with, or a line to boot from my thumb drive. I believe what is happening before the boot order can take effect. The old Ubuntu is trying to load grub but then i

Comment: is your question half composed?

Comment: @Sathya: I guess he must've deleted his XP partition too, in the middle of writing this...

Answer (score 1):

You need to boot from a Windows XP install disk. When the installer starts, press "r" to repair a Windows installation. When the recovery console appears, you may need to type "1" to select your Windows installation, and you will then be prompted for the administrator password (this is probably blank, even if you have set the password on your own user account). Once you have logged in, run `fixmbr` followed by `fixboot`.

Comment: ther is no other way thought the grub recovery ?

Comment: You could attempt to install GRUB within the Windows partition... but I don't think this is practical at all. You should definitely go with restoring the Windows bootloader.

Comment: sounds like fun do hav the commands ;)

Comment: ssh -1 000.000.000

Comment: i got another ? wat dose this do rm . *

Comment: you've really got to be careful entering commands that you get off the internet! rm is a command to remove (delete) files.

Comment: `rm . *`, though, would result in an error (. is the current directory, and rm will not remove directories without the recursive option) and then delete the contents of the current folder. I think this command was given by a malicious person in error.

Comment: to delete all file from a system, `sudo rm -rf /` sounds better

Answer (score 0):

You can repair using the Windows XP install disk as suggested above. 
Another alternative is to install Ubuntu again on the same partition. That way, you will get your grub re-installed (along with Ubuntu) and you can then use/boot windows.
To install ubuntu, you should be able to boot from CD/DVD drive or a USB drive